# An "Untitled" app icon is created on iPhone home screen after restart even after deletion

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

I have a white app icon titled "Untitled". When I click on it, it opens a Safari window with Untitled title window. After deleting it, if I restart the iPhone, it gets created again.

Is there a way to delete it permanently?

Answer (score 1):

The procedure will require for you to SSH into your device.

Navigate to "private/var/mobile/library/webclips" and delete any clips (folders) entries.

By deleting these entries, it will eradicate the untitled icons appearing on your springboard.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the profile from the settings app that installed that web clip.

Comment: Well that sucks. Is that a malware/security issue? Or is it a link to a porn vid or something he added to his home page that has since gone dead?

Comment: very unlikely, @iMerchant - most profiles are MDM for work or organization and not malicious. I suppose some pirated software tries to use "enterprise" certs so who knows what was installed there.